# I need a faster solution to perform a Select on a table with multiple specific matchings in a 1-to-n related table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

### Overview

I have the following structure in a system, where the user can save attributes to jobs, which he can name on his own. One attribute can have 2 possible values, a user value and a system value.
I am trying to filter the jobs based on the attributes, where either the user value or the system value can hit.

### Current situation

table jobs

| id | company_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | active |
| 2 | 2 | created |
| 3 | 3 | created |
| 4 | 12 | inactive |

table job_data

| job_id | field | value_user | value_xml |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | city | Berlin |  |
| 1 | phone | 1234567 |  |
| 1 | type | fulltime |  |
| 2 | city | New York |  |
| 2 | phone | 33333333 |  |
| 2 | type | parttime |  |
| 3 | city |  | Berlin |
| 3 | phone |  | 123 |
| 3 | type |  | fulltime |

Indexes:

| Table | Key_name | Column_name | Collation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jobs | PRIMARY | id | A |
| job_data | job_data_jobs_id_foreign | job_id | A |

The user now has to filter for multiple attributes, for example: "show me all jobs with city Berlin and phone 123". This would show job 1 and 3, since they both have Berlin in one of the city-values and a phone number like 123 in one of the phone values.

I had several working solutions, but now we are having 120,000 active jobs in the database, having over a million attributes and our code is not fast enough. This is our current solution:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM job_data
    WHERE job_data.job_id = jobs.id
    AND job_data.field = "city" AND (job_data.value_xml LIKE "%Martinhaven%" OR job_data.value_user LIKE "%Martinhaven%")
) > 0
AND
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM job_data
    WHERE job_data.jobposting_id = jobs.id
    AND job_data.field = "category" AND (job_data.value_xml LIKE "%omnis%" OR job_data.value_user LIKE "%omnis%")
) > 0;
```

output:

| id | company_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | active |
| 3 | 3 | created |

this has been simplified, we have around 6 filter possibilities, but they are all of the same kind, so I only posted 2 of them.

### Question

Can anyone tell me, how I can do this a lot faster? We currently need 5-10 seconds for one select. Ofc we could restructure the database to make it faster to filter, but we are still trying to prevent that, since it is a bigger system in construction.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you [show us your indexes](https://use-the-index-luke.com/), please?

Comment: Can you ever have both value_user and value_xml set? If so, what then? if not, merge the columns and add a column to indicate where the value is from.

Comment: Why are you counting rows? Use `exists`.

Comment: @Schwern yes, they can be both be filled with different values. Indexes: jobposting_data 1 jobposting_data_jobposting_id_foreign 1 jobposting_id
and id PRIMARY of course. Thanks a lot already

Comment: @Stu how could I not see that.. thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `jobposting_id`?

Comment: Sorry, the index are hard to read in a comment. Could you [edit them into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70644566/edit)?

Comment: @Schwern I added the indexes, but it's just one primary and one foreign key

Comment: Do you need to do full wildcard searches? They're difficult to index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

- Multiple value fields.
- `like '%word%'` is tricky to index.

[tl;dr demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=392cc93ff6793805ae8351f662d00e71)

---

## Fix the schema

Change `job_data` to a single value and a source.

```
job_id  field  value   source
1       city   Berlin  user
3       city   Berlin  xml
```

```
-- Add value and source columns, nullable for now.
alter table job_data add value varchar(255), add source varchar(255);

-- If value_user is not null or blank, add it to value with a source of user.
update job_data
set value = value_user, source = 'user'
where coalesce(value_user, '') <> '';

-- Same for value_xml, source of xml.
update job_data
set value = value_xml, source = 'xml'
where value_xml is not null;

-- Drop the old value columns.
alter table job_data
  drop value_xml, drop value_user;
```

Now we can enforce not null on value and source to avoid bad data.

```
alter table job_data
  modify value varchar(255) not null,
  modify source varchar(255) not null;
```

We can also enforce that a job can only have one value per field. Or per field and source.

```
-- If a job can have multiple sources for a field.
alter table add unique(job_id, field, source);

-- If it cannot.
alter table add unique(job_id, field);
```

And if you need to maintain compatibility, make a view.

```
create view old_job_data as
  select
    job_id,
    field,
    case source when 'user' then value end as value_user,
    case source when 'xml' then value end as value_xml
  from job_data;
```

This fixes a number of problems.

- You can have as many sources as you like.
- You can ensure the value is not null.
- You can avoid duplicates.
- You don't need to check the value in two places.
- Indexing is easier.

---

## The query

With that fixed, the query is much simpler.

To find which jobs match both field/value pairs, normally you'd do an [`intersect`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/). But MySQL does not have `intersect`, so we emulate it with a self-join.

```
select * from jobs
where job_id in (
  select distinct j1.job_id
  from job_data j1
  inner join job_data j2 on j1.job_id = j2.job_id
  where
    (j1.field = 'city' and j1.value like '%York%')
    and
    (j2.field = 'type' and j2.value like '%time%')

)
```

You don't *have* to change the table, you can do `j1.field = 'city' and (j1.value_xml like '%York%' or j1.value_user like '%York%')`, but it makes it so much easier.

---

## Indexing

In MySQL, [`like '%word%'` will not use a simple index. It has to scan each row with a matching field. Simple indexes only work for `like 'word%'`](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning). Other databases have [special indexes for this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.8). I don't know of a solution for MySQL.

At minimum, index `field` so you can at least find the rows matching `field` quickly.

```
create index job_data_field_idx on job_data(field);
```

Now instead of scanning every row, it will only scan the rows which match the field.

Decide if you really need full wildcard searches. Or do you need to clean up your data before inserting it? If you can get rid of the wildcard indexes, this index will make the search nearly instant.

```
create index job_data_field_vaue_idx on job_data(value, field);
```

Comment: Thanks for your great communication, Schwern, I used a lot from that and will continue to improve the queries.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 1 correlated subquery that aggregates for each condition and for each row of the table `jobs`, use conditional aggregation once:

```
SELECT job_id 
FROM job_data
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING SUM(field = 'city' AND (value_xml LIKE '%Martinhaven%' OR value_user LIKE '%Martinhaven%')) > 0
   AND SUM(field = 'category' AND (value_xml LIKE '%omnis%' OR value_user LIKE '%omnis%')) > 0
   AND .....
```

to get all the `job_id`s that you want and use them with the operator IN:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE job_id IN (
  SELECT job_id 
  FROM job_data
  GROUP BY job_id
  HAVING SUM(field = 'city' AND (value_xml LIKE '%Martinhaven%' OR value_user 
  LIKE '%Martinhaven%')) > 0
     AND SUM(field = 'category' AND (value_xml LIKE '%omnis%' OR value_user 
  LIKE '%omnis%')) > 0
     AND .....
);
```

If the number of `job_id`s returned by the subquery is small I believe that the performance of this query will be better.

All the `> 0` inequalities can be removed from the code, but I left them there for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot to that will help when using an unsargable criteria with *like '%...'*, however you are needlessly burning CPU and IO by doing a `count(*)` for each searched criteria.

It's *possible* the optimizer could spot this and optimize it internally as an *exists* operation, but it's always preferable to be explicit

```
select * 
from jobs j
where exists (
    select 1 job_data d
    where d.job_id = j.id
    and d.field = "city" and (d.value_xml like "%Martinhaven%" or d.value_user like "%Martinhaven%")
)
```

With an entity-attribute model it would be more efficient if all the values were in the same column. That might be too much of a change to be implemented initially so you should also try multiple criteria to check each column separately rather than using *or*. This would be most beneficial with an index for each (on *field, Value_xml* and *field, value_user*).

```
select * 
from jobs j
where exists (select 1 job_data d  where d.job_id = j.id and d.field = "city" and d.value_xml like "%Martinhaven%") 
union
select * 
from jobs j
where exists (select 1 job_data d  where d.job_id = j.id and d.field = "city" and d.value_user like "%Martinhaven%")
```

You might find this yields better performance since each could use an index to seek to just the *city* rows and then scan just until there is a match; at best it can exist almost immediately, at worst it's no worse than the existing table scan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Stu! I really appreciate it and I used exactly that pattern, too bad I can only mark one answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution:

Instead of

```
( SELECT COUNT(*) ... ) > 0 )
```

write

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )
```

The latter will stop scanning when the first occurrence is found.  (The former has to look at the entire table.)

The real villains are

- `OR` -- which does not optimize well
- `LIKE '%...'` -- the 'leading wildcard' prevents use of any index.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what indexes exist.

Another problem is the use of the clumsy and inefficient "Entity-Attribute-Value" schema pattern.

And I worry about "XML".

Now for something more encouraging.  A `FULLEXT` on a column that contained the data being searched, plus `MATCH(col) AGAINST('+Martinhaven +omnis' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` would be really fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean "And I worry about "XML", I can't see how that helps?